# Find constant when a quadratic equation has natural roots

Tags: functions, quadratics

> Given $a\in\mathbb{R}$, such that the two roots in $$f(x)=x^2+ax+(2a+319)$$
> are both positive integers. Find $a$.

I've found that$$D=a^2-4\times(2a+319) = a^2-8a-1276$$

Since the two roots are integers,
$$D=N^2, n\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$a^2-8a-1276=N^2$$

That's all I got. How can I move further?

Comment: Use Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $D=a^2-8a\color{red}-1276$

You have\begin{align}a^2-8a-1276=N^2&\iff(a-4)^2-1292=N^2\\&\iff1292=(a-4-N)(a-4+N).\end{align}So, for any way of writing $1292$ as $k\times l$ ($k,l\in\Bbb Z$), solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a-4-N=k\\a-4+N=l.\end{array}\right.$$For instance, if $k=-34$, and $l=-38$, you will get $a=-32$ and the roots will be $15$ and $17$.

Comment: The number $1340$ should be $1292$.

Comment: Sure. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=(x-r)(x-s)$. Then by Vieta,
\begin{align*}
r+s & = -a \\
rs & = 2a+319.
\end{align*}
Adding yields the Diophantine equation
$$
rs+2r+2s=319,
$$
which has the solution $(r,s)=(15,17),(17,15)$ in positive integers (there are only a few cases to check since $r,s\le 105$ and both $r,s$ are odd). So $a=-32$ is the only solution.